# How to set the text to bold in WFP paragraph?

Tags: wpf

I have in a FlowDocument some Paragraphs.

```
  <Paragraph> Hello </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph> World </Paragraph>
```

How to set the text to bold in WFP paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Bold class from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.bold(v=vs.100).aspx

```
 <Paragraph><Bold>Bolded</Bold></Paragraph>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Paragraph> Hello <Bold>World</Bold> </Paragraph>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Paragraph>
        <Bold>
              bold text here
        </Bold>
    </Paragraph>
```